# TypeScript build error TS5023

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to compile TypeScript & NodeJS an getting this error any help?

tsc --version => Version 2.7.2

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strict'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Updated, added tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "lib": ["es2015"],                            

    "sourceMap": true,                     
    "strict": true,                           
    "esModuleInterop": true, 

    "mapRoot": "./map"                      
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Doing `tsc` on the command line would probably just give you the globally installed version. Is your _local_ typescript version updated?

Answer (score 8):

I have found my mistake forget to call local version of TypeScript `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --init`

Comment: What do you mean by `call local version of TypeScript`. Do you have an example?

Comment: You mean you weren't using the local version of Typescript in the project... ?

Comment: I had a similar issue where I was using ntsc npm package as a part of an example. Changing to use the correct tsc command fixed half my issues.

Answer (score 3):

npm install --save-dev typescript@3.1.6 fixed it at my side.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed for my was installing global the typescript via npm package manager:

npm install -g typescript

And then the tsc compiler was available:

e.g.: tsc -p src/server/ -w